# Update join using SQLAlchemy/SQLite using multiple criteria

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have set up ORM on a SQLite database successfully using the following code to reflect the database:

```
Base = automap_base()
conn_string = 'sqlite:///' + wd.replace('\\','\\\\') + sqlite_filename
engine = create_engine(conn_string, echo=True)
@event.listens_for(Table, "column_reflect")
def reflect_col(inspector, table, column_info):
    column_info['key'] = column_info['name'].replace(' ', '_')
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
PpoAward = Base.classes.ppo_award
Accident = Base.classes.accident
session = Session(engine)
```

I am successfully executing basic queries like this:

```
# delete existing accident records for this quarter
session.query(Accident).\
    filter(and_(Accident.accounting_year==acct_year,
                Accident.accounting_qtr == acct_qtr)).delete()
    session.commit()
```

I'm trying to do an update join on the ppo_award table, but being relatively new to this I am getting completely lost in the SQLAlchemy documentation.  I don't think there is already a straightforward answer on stackoverflow.

I would like to be able to replicate this SQL in an elegant way in Python:

```
UPDATE ppo_award
SET p.ppo_award_accident_id = a.accident_id
FROM ppo_award p
    INNER JOIN accident a ON p.field_1=a.field_1 AND p.field_2=a.field_2 AND p.field_3=a.field_3
```

Fields 1, 2 and 3 have a unique constraint in the accident table.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: SQLAlchemy supports multiple table updates: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#multi-table-updates, but unfortunately not for SQLite, though it would actually support them.